# Changing directories while having a file open

Tags: python, c

Say I have a python script that opens a file to write:

The python modules also call C modules that change the directory with

```
chdir()
```

Will the python script still have the file open and be able to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files are tracked by file handles, and once open for a particular file, stays open to that file until closed.